# How to display these buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an application in my fiddle where the user selects their preferred options and answers.

To use the app the user first selects an option from the grid, lets say option "3" for example, it will displays buttons A to C at the bottom.

The user then lets say type in the number 2 in the Number of Answers Textbox, this means that the user can only select 2 answers from A to C.

Now if the user selects Answers A and B, then those buttons turn green to show they have been selected.

Now if the user clicks on the "Add Question" button, it will add the answer in a new row at the bottom. This is the problem I am getting at the moment. What it is suppose to do if you follow the example above is to show all three buttons A to C with A and B selected (green color) but at it just displays the three buttons with none of them selected.

So what do I need to do to be able to display all the buttons from the option in the table row showing the buttons selected from the option, (if you follow aboves example it should display in the row A to C with A and B selected)?

Below is my code which creates the new row and displays the buttons in the row:

This can be found near the bottom of the javascript code in my jsfiddle which you can access [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C443c/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you can write the function like this

```
function insertQuestion(form) {

    var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    var $answer = $("<td class='answer'></td>");

    $("#optionAndAnswer .answerBtns:visible").clone().appendTo($answer);

    $tr.append($answer);

    $('#qandatbl').append($tr);

}
```

Use this if you want to clear the click handler

```
$("#optionAndAnswer .answerBtns:visible").clone().attr('onclick', '').appendTo($answer);
```